# Change color of bootstrap 4 beta table row border?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the border-top color of Bootstrap table.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Parent</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mama</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS** I've tried

```
table > tr{
  border-top: black;
}

table > tr > td{
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/o9b17p2d/43/

As seen in the fiddle.
I'd like to change the color of the line between Parent & Mama.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have used a wrong selector in `table > tr > td {` and `table > tr {`
>   because `thead` is direct children for table and no `tr`.

so, change like this:

```
table > thead > tr > td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```css
table > thead > tr > td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Parent</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Mama</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have placed a wrong code.Try this

```
.table td, .table th{
  border-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this  in your css.

```
thead{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6c5ce7;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o9b17p2d/45/

I hope it will help

Comment: This will color the whole td

Comment: @BjörnC did you ever try that in css?

Comment: I watched your fiddle. But now it's better ;D

Comment: Is there a way to make it glow?

Answer (score 0):

So that you dont effect all other tables in your page/site.
The easiest way to do this - is to give the  element an id, and then target it in CSS using the id.

```
#no-top-border-td {
  border-top: none
}

<td id="no-top-border-td">Mama</td>
```

or you could add that as a style to the actual  element

```
<td style="border-top: none" />
```

both of these have a high priority when the CSS is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use border-bottom property for row in thead.Add this code in css

```
 .table thead tr td{
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```